# Get datetime and computername in comments in a standard template

Tags: matlab

I am creating a test standard template

```
%
%   Description: 
%
   Author = ['Author : ' getenv('computername')]
%   
  Date =['Date : ' datestr(datetime('now' ,'Format','d-MMM-y'))]
%
%   Comment: 
%
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% do something
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

and my call function is

```
function [] = newmfile(V)
 V = [V '.m']
 copyfile('StandardTemplate.m',V)
edit(V)
```

so when a person writes

```
newmfile Test
```

It creates a newfile of the template i created but now the problem is I know how to get current computer name and date as I have written but how can i make it so it appears in comments and gets the result of the code above in "Author" and "Date" as a string so i get the template as

```
%
%   Description: 
%
%   Author : This Computer 
%   
%   Date :  26-Jun-2016
%
%   Comment: 
%
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% do something
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**UPDATE:**
I have tried creating through a text file it works but still a better solution would be appreciated

```
function [] = newmfile(V)
V = [V '.m'];
per = '%';
Author = [ getenv('computername')];
Date =['Date : ' datestr(datetime('now' ,'Format','d-MMM-y'))];
copyfile('StandardTemplate.txt','TempTextfile.txt')
replaceLine = 4;
fileID = fopen('TempTextfile.txt','r+');
for k=1:(replaceLine-1);
   fgetl(fileID);
end
fseek(fileID,0,'cof');
fprintf(fileID,'%s   Author: %s\n%s\n%s   %s\n%s\n%s',per,Author,per,per,Date,per,per);
fclose all;
copyfile('TempTextfile.txt',V)
delete('TempTextfile.txt')
edit(V)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your original template using your own templating syntax to indicate what substitutions should be made when the template is loaded. Here I've just used `$command$` to indicate a command that should be run to replace commands with the result of those commands.

```
%
%   Description: 
%
%   Author: $getenv('computername')$
%   
%   Date : $datestr(datetime('now' ,'Format','d-MMM-y'))$
%
%   Comment: 
%
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% do something
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then you'd process it using `regexprep` which will match any `$command$` appearance and then rather than doing a static string replacement, we use the `${function_to_run}` syntax for the replacement string and inside of that we have it evaluate the match (excluding the `$` at either end) and return the result to be inserted into the string.

```
fid = fopen('template.m', 'r');
contents = fread(fid, '*char')';
fclose(fid);

% Replace all strings between $ and $ with their evaluated version
newcontents = regexprep(contents, '\$(.*?)\$', '${eval($1)}');

% Write to new file
fid = fopen('destination.m', 'w');
fwrite(fid, newcontents);
fclose(fid);
```

Comment: Thanks ! I will try this